# How can I load a Child mesh to a Parent one?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a facial mesh with a separate eye mesh. In Blender, the face is defined as a parent and the eyes as a child. Now I try to load the whole into three.js. How can I do this?

With the textures I have also a problem it can be loaded only one. Can someone help me? Thanks

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();        
        loader.load( "./three/models/JSON/Blender/DM_Face.json", addModelToScene );           //function( geometry, material ) {
      //loader.load( "./three/models/JSON/Blender/DM_Eye.json", addModelToScene );

    //var materials = [material1, material2];
    //var meshFaceMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );

function addModelToScene( geometry, materials ) { //sphereGeometry1, sphereMaterial1 ) {            
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({morphTargets: true, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./three/models/JSON/Blender/DM.fbm/RyEddie_face_1001.jpg')});    
var Mouth = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./three/models/JSON/Blender/DM.fbm/RyEddie_mouth_1005.jpg')});

        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material, Mouth )          
        mesh.scale.set( 17, 13, 13 );
        mesh.position.x = 0;            //Position (x = nach rechts+ links-)  
        mesh.position.y = -17;          //Position (y = nach oben +, unten-)
        mesh.position.z = 0;            //Position (z = nach vorne +, hinten-)          
        scene.add( mesh )   

    //var sphereMaterial1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./three/models/JSON/Blender/DM.fbm/RyEddie_eyes01_1007.jpg')});
            //sphareMesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeometry1, sphereMaterial1 )
            //sphareMesh1.scale.set( 30, 30, 30 );
        //sphareMesh1.position.x = 0;       //Position (x = nach rechts+ links-)  
        //sphareMesh1.position.y = 0;       //Position (y = nach oben +, unten-)
        //sphareMesh1.position.z = 0;       //Position (z = nach vorne +, hinten-)              
        //scene.add( sphareMesh1 );         


            mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( mesh );
            var clip = THREE.AnimationClip.CreateFromMorphTargetSequence( 'test', geometry.morphTargets, 30 );
        mixer.clipAction( clip ).setDuration( 6 ).play();

        };
```

In the JSON file, the texture materials is defined as follows

```
"materials":[{      
        "depthTest":true,
        "transparent":false,
        "depthWrite":true,
        "colorSpecular":[0.5,0.5,0.5],
        "DbgName":"Face",
        "wireframe":false,
        "visible":true,
        "DbgIndex":5,
        "DbgColor":61166,
        "doubleSided":false,
        "specularCoef":103,
        "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
        "opacity":1,
        "colorDiffuse":[0.8,0.8,0.8],
        "shading":"phong",
        "blending":1
      },{
        "depthTest":true,
        "transparent":true,
        "depthWrite":true,
        "DbgName":"Eyelashes",
        "wireframe":false,
        "visible":true,
        "DbgIndex":0,
        "DbgColor":15658734,
        "doubleSided":false,
        "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
        "opacity":0,
        "colorDiffuse":[0.0414118,0.0379608,0.0310588],
        "shading":"lambert",
        "blending":1
     },{
        "depthTest":true,
        "transparent":true,
        "depthWrite":true,
        "colorSpecular":[0.5,0.5,0.5],
        "DbgName":"EyeMoisture",
        "wireframe":false,
        "visible":true,
        "DbgIndex":14,
        "DbgColor":15658734,
        "doubleSided":false,
        "specularCoef":103,
        "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
        "opacity":0,
        "colorDiffuse":[0.8,0.8,0.8],
        "shading":"phong",
        "blending":1
      },{
        "depthTest":true,
        "transparent":false,
        "depthWrite":true,
        "colorSpecular":[0.5,0.5,0.5],
        "DbgName":"Torso",
        "wireframe":false,
        "visible":true,
        "DbgIndex":9,
        "DbgColor":15658734,
        "doubleSided":false,
        "specularCoef":103,
        "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
        "opacity":1,
        "colorDiffuse":[0.8,0.8,0.8],
        "shading":"phong",
        "blending":1
     },{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can technically parent one mesh to another, but it could confuse the renderer. It's better to start thinking in `Group`s.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/Group

Consider the following simplified code:

```
var head = new THREE.Group();
loader.load("face.json", function(geometry, materials){
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  head.add(mesh);
});
loader.load("eye.json", function(geometry, materials){
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  head.add(mesh);
});
scene.add(head);
```

(*Side Note: The `Mesh` constructor only takes two parameters. [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/Mesh)*)

From here, transforming the `head` will cause both the `face` mesh and the `eye` mesh to follow. This applies to all transformations (position, rotation, scale, skew)--the transformation will cascade down into all meshes contained in `head`.

You can even nest `Group`s, so you can give hierarchy to your model, but that conversation is for another question.

three.js r87

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It needs the "THREE.JSONLoader" nor? I get nothing more on the screen.

Comment: @Tom **1)** Yes, you need JSONLoader (or any other loader). My code was only for example. **2)** jsFiddle won't be an appropriate platform on which to test this (you can't reference your JSON files by relative paths, you'd need to host them with open CORS permissions). Try this code locally, and look at the errors the console is giving you.

Comment: oh yes, thanks for the hint. I have used fiddel only to show the code better and have not assumed that this is running. I use the code locally and try to run it. At the moment it is not yet possible. Do they see what it could be?

Comment: @Tom I've updated my example code with a line that I see is also missing from your code. Just like when you add a mesh to a scene, `scene.add(head);` adds the group to the scene (thereby adding the meshes). Without it, you'll see nothing.

Comment: Yes @TheJim01, now the model Face appears.The eyes are not there yet. I have rebuilt the following.

Answer (score -1):

@TheJim01 it looks like this at the moment.

```js
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
 //var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
   //loader.load( "./three/models/JSON/Blender/Face.json", addModelToScene ); 
 
  
var head = new THREE.Group();
  loader.load("./three/models/JSON/Blender/Face.json", function(geometry, materials){
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({morphTargets: true, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./three/models/JSON/Blender/DM.fbm/RyEddie_face_1001.jpg')});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  head.add( mesh );
  });
  
  loader.load("./three/models/JSON/Blender/Eyes.json", function(geometry, materials){
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({morphTargets: true, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./three/models/JSON/Blender/DM.fbm/eyes_1001.jpg')});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  head.add( mesh );
  });
  
  
function addModelToScene( geometry, materials ) {   
      
   mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material )   
   mesh.scale.set( 13, 13, 13 );
   mesh.position.x = 0;     
   mesh.position.y = -25;   
   mesh.position.z = 0;       
   scene.add( mesh )    
  
  mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( mesh );
  
  var clip = THREE.AnimationClip.CreateFromMorphTargetSequence( 'test', geometry.morphTargets, 30 );  
  
  mixer.clipAction( clip ).setDuration( 6 );
  var action = mixer.clipAction( clip );
  
  Play.onclick = function Play() {  
  action.play();  
  }
  Stop.onclick = function Stop() {  
  action.stop();  
  }  
  
  };
```

Comment: why are you posting mutliple answers to your own question?

Comment: Because I have not yet figured out how to insert an additional code snippet as an extended question.

Answer (score -1):

@TheJim01 Yes, now the model Face appears. The eyes are not there yet. And the animation is no longer running. I have rebuilt the following. The interesting thing is that when I take out the texture, the face does not appear any more?

```js
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
   
 var head = new THREE.Group();
  loader.load("./three/models/JSON/Blender/Face.json", function(geometry, materials){
 var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./three/models/JSON/Blender/DM.fbm/face_1001.jpg')});
 var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  mesh.scale.set( 13, 13, 13 );
  mesh.position.x = 0;    
  mesh.position.y = -25;       
  mesh.position.z = 0;        
  head.add( mesh );
  });
  
  loader.load("./three/models/JSON/Blender/Eyes.json", function(geometry, materials){
 var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./three/models/JSON/Blender/DMWBSABAB.fbm/eyes_1001.jpg')});
 var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  mesh.scale.set( 13, 13, 13 );
  mesh.position.x = 0;    
  mesh.position.y = 0;       
  mesh.position.z = 0;       
  head.add( mesh );
  });
  
  scene.add( head );
   
  
 function addModelToScene( geometry, materials ) {
  
  morphTargets: true    
  //scene.add( mesh );
  
  
  mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( mesh, head );
  
  var clip = THREE.AnimationClip.CreateFromMorphTargetSequence( 'gallop', geometry.morphTargets, 30 );  
  
  mixer.clipAction( clip ).setDuration( 6 );
  var action = mixer.clipAction( clip );
  
  Play.onclick = function Play() {  
  action.play();  
  }
  Stop.onclick = function Stop() {  
  action.stop();  
  }  
  
  };
```